# Hp Compaq Pro 6305 Microtower, Upgrade RAM memory

Tags: memory

Im pretty new to custom pcs but i would like to upgrade the ram as the pc has gotten pretty slow.
Theres four ram slots and there are two 4.00 GB DDR3 SDRAM 799MHz RAM sticks in it idealy i would like 16GB of RAM in total. I do not know which or what type or ram i should get that will be compatible. Any suggestions?

Comment: See [How to find which RAM to get for my computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1543730/how-to-find-which-ram-to-get-for-my-computer)

Comment: The thing is that DDR3 is pretty expensive nowadays, so look at a local price comparison site if 2x8 or 2x4 is cheaper, in the case of 2x8 you replace the RAM, in the case of 2x4 you add the RAM, but do note it has to be DDR3 else it won't fit

Answer (score 1):

[Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/hp---compaq/hp-compaq-pro-6305-small-form-factor) and [Kingston](https://www.kingston.com/en/memory/search/model/80027/hp-hpe-business-pro-6305-mt-sff) both have compatibility pages for this comptuer. You will likely see more improvement by upgrading your storage to a SSD (aslo in the linked lists) than you will from increasing the RAM.